# How to make mod_python to wait for the updated text file to read?

Tags: python, cgi, mod-python, textinput, pyinotify

```
import cgi

def fill():
   s = """\
<html><body>
<form method="get" action="./show">
<p>Type a word: <input type="text" name="word">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"</p>
</form></body></html>
"""
   return s

# Receive the Request object
def show(req):
   # The getfirst() method returns the value of the first field with the
   # name passed as the method argument
   word = req.form.getfirst('word', '')
   print "Creating a text file with the write() method."
   text_file = open("/var/www/cgi-bin/input.txt", "w")
   text_file.write(word)
   text_file.close()
   # Escape the user input to avoid script injection attacks
   #word = cgi.escape(word)

   '''Input triggers the application to start its process'''

   output_file=open("/var/www/cgi-bin/output.txt", "r").read()
   s = """\
<html><body>
<p>The submitted word was "%s"</p>
<p><a href="./fill">Submit another word!</a></p>
</body></html>
"""
   return s % output_file
```

This is my program, here i need to send text to my application and output of the application is written on a file called output.txt, But the application takes some time depending upon the size of the input, problem is this statement `output_file=open("/var/www/cgi-bin/output.txt", "r").read()` is reading output.txt before the application writes new data over the file. I want that output_file should wait till the application finishes execution and should take updated data from output.txt.

I tried a lot but couldn't figure out, Please help me out through this :)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have three different requests that come in to your application at the same time.  All of them are going to be attempting to write to and read from **the same files at the same time**.

For your above code to work with concurrent requests, you need to use unique filenames for each request/response.  Come up with a strategy to change include a unique identifier (e.g. timestamp + client ip address) within the filenames for your input and output files.

Comment: Actually i thought i should wait till application has finished its execution, it shouldn't enter to this statement `output_file=open("/var/www/cgi-bin/output.txt", "r").read()` before the application finishes its job
Program should continue only after output.txt is updated by application..